# I feel like this "proof" is incorrect, but I don't know why?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm in an introductory differential equations class, and while studying, I worked out the following "proof", which I feel is almost certainly incorrect but I'm not sure why. If I had to guess, it would be some sort of error caused by dividing by 0 or with the boundary wherein the solution is valid, but I'm not sure.

*Let *$y = f(x)$*. Then,*

$\frac{dy}{dx} = f'(x)$*. Solving as a separable differential equation,*

$$\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{f'(x)} \rightarrow \int dx = \int \frac{1}{f'(x)} dy$$

$$x = \frac{y}{f'(x)} + C \rightarrow y = xf'(x) + Cf'(x)$$

$$f(x) = xf'(x) + Cf'(x)$$

I can find many counterexamples which show that this is not true, for example:

$$f(x) = x + \ln(x) + \sin(x)$$
Plugging into the above formula $f(x) = xf'(x) + Cf'(x)$ gives
$$f(x) = x + \ln(x) + \sin(x) \neq x\bigl(1 + \frac{1}{x} + \cos(x)\bigr) + C\bigl(1 + \frac{1}{x} + \cos(x)\bigr)$$
for which I can think of no constants $C$ for which this is true.

Comment: When you write $\int \frac{1}{f'(x)}\,dy$, you treat $f'(x)$ as if it is entirely independent of $y$. This is incorrect.

Comment: To add to what Ben said: This is indeed a separable equation, but if you want to separate the variables, then $f'(x)$ has to go with $dx$ on the $x$ side. Then things won't come out so strange.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{f'(x)} \rightarrow \int dx = \int \frac{1}{f'(x)} dy$$
So far so good.

Unfortunately, the integral on the RHS does not simplify because $f'(x)$ is not a constant.